# Pytorch matmul - RuntimeError: "addmm_impl_cpu_" not implemented for 'Half'

Tags: pytorch

When I am running pytorch matmul, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omrastogi/Desktop/Side/One-Class-Classification-Customer-Complaints/pattern.py", line 71, in <module>
    print(obj.infer(list([df.text[0]]), list([df.reason[0]])))
  File "/home/omrastogi/Desktop/Side/One-Class-Classification-Customer-Complaints/pattern.py", line 45, in infer
    cos_sm = self.batch_cosine_similarity(enc1, enc2)
  File "/home/omrastogi/Desktop/Side/One-Class-Classification-Customer-Complaints/pattern.py", line 51, in batch_cosine_similarity
    dot_prd = torch.matmul(inp1, inp2.transpose(0, 1))
RuntimeError: "addmm_impl_cpu_" not implemented for 'Half'
```

inp1 --> [1*256]

inp2 --> [1*256]

Comment: I encounter this issue while running a model on CPU with `torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.HalfTensor)`

I fixed the issue by removing the code above.

Comment: @hsc Where can I find this piece of code?

Comment: @zaki41 it exists in my personal codebase so I removed it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The error was throwing because the data type of operands was float16.
Changing it back to float32 solved the problem. I guess float16 is for GPU implementation only.

Comment: How did you do this exactly?

Comment: This converts the tensor to float32 dtype: `inp1.type(torch.float32)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert it by type casting it to float32.

```
inp1.type(torch.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was triggered by the data type of operands being `float16`.

Note that `float16` (halfPrecision) is specifically designed for GPU implementation. It should not be used in CPU implementation as it is currently unavailable for that platform. For CPU implementation, use `float32` instead.

If you encounter this error on GPU, you can resolve it by adjusting the setting as follows:

```py
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.HalfTensor)
```